# OneNote Section Level Permissions

Tags: permissions, sharepoint, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I've got a user who wishes to share a OneNote notebook with other users. The one caveat is that he was different users to have access to different sections within the notebook (ie. User A gets access to one section 1, user B only to section 2, etc.). Is this possible, and how would I go about setting it up? The notebook will be shared with users on SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting-up different notebooks is indeed the preferred way. But OneNote will respect the permissions that are set on the server. Not the expert, but I believe Sharepoint 2010 allows file-level permissions although it is buried in the UI. On a network share, you want to allow deny read/deny write but you want to allow listing permissions. Not sure if Sharepoint can limit listing permissions but you want to make sure to not disallow listing sections (which means they will all show-up in the UI but some of them will be in error state for the users who do not have access.).

Comment: But a single file makes up a OneNote notebook.  A OneNote notebook is a single file.  So, there is no way you can use user permissions at any level smaller than complete notebooks.

Comment: When you add a OneNote notebook to a SharePoint document library, it ends up being uploaded as several folders/files. Breaking permissions inherritance within SharePoint and setting item level permissions on each separate item allowed me to do what I wanted to. A little bit of a pain to manage, but it works. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @Evan: I did not realise that Notebooks were split up on SharePoint, as I keep mine on SkyDrive.  I think I'll try migrating them to SharePoint then.

Comment: @paradroid is wrong. OneNote Notebooks are NOT a single file. There is one .onetoc file that is for opening the file, and there are individual files for each section of the notebook. I have not tested the function of adjusting permissions on the individual section files of a notebook, but it is not true that OneNote stores an entire notebook in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to use separate passwords to protect each section within the notebook, in OneNote.

I do not think that is a very good idea though.  I think a better solution would be to use separate notebooks instead, and manage access within SharePoint.

Comment: If the notebook is stored on SkyDrive, pages in a password-protected section are invisible. Not sure if it works for SharePoint though.